# (PHP) Shopping Cart

Tags: php, html, mysql, mariadb

I am trying to create a shopping cart with PHP, but, once the user leaves the cart area, all of the products disappear. That's what I'm trying to do:

```
  <?php foreach($almofadas as $almofadas):?>
            <form action="cart.php" method="GET">
            <div class="base col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="uploads/<?php echo $almofadas['imagem'];  ?>" alt="">
                        <div class="content-c">
                            <div class="row-p">
                                <div class="details">

                                    <span><?php echo $almofadas['pnome'] ; ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price">R$ <?php echo $almofadas['preço'];?> </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $almofadas['p_id']?>">

                            <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><button class="buttons-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Detalhes</button></div>
                                <div><button class="buttons-2" type="submit">Adicionar ao Carrinho</a> </button></div> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>

        <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Now the cart system:

```
<?php
session_start();


require_once 'conn.php';



$_SESSION['id'] =  $_GET['id'];
$result_pedido = "SELECT * FROM tb_produtos WHERE p_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'"; 
$resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($conn, $result_pedido);
$pedidos = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado_pedido, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
?>
```

Here I can only add one product and, I can't save it into a $_SESSION, having said that the product disapears once iI leave the cart.

```
<?php foreach($pedidos as $pedidos):?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="cart-img">
                        <img src="uploads/<?php echo $pedidos['imagem'];?>" width="125px">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="cart-model">
                        <?php echo $pedidos['pnome'] ; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="cart-quantity">
                        <input class="i-quantity" type="number" value="1">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="cart-price">
                        R$<?php echo $pedidos['preço'] ; ?>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Is this academic code or for a production site? If it's for learning there's a lot of important things to pick up on here. If it's for a production site this is going to be trouble and you should look at building on an established platform like [Magento](https://magento.com) or [Laravel](https://laravel.com).

Comment: Would you explain the part where you mention a tab !

Comment: We can't see the problem here... does opening (preloading) the tab or leaving it calls a script or has sthg to do  with Sessions or DB ? just a Hint :)

Answer (score -1):

If you check this line:

```php
$_SESSION['id'] =  $_GET['id'];
```

This mean the "id" in your `$_SESSION` is always set to `$_GET['id']`, even if it is empty. So it is reset every time the user visit a page.

You should:

1. have some mechanism to store your shopping cart content. There is none in your code; and
2. have a way to check if the user visits a new id before storing it to shopping cart.

For example,

```php
<?php

/**
 * This only make sense if this script is called
 * by some AJAX / javascript interaction to specifically
 * add a new item to cart.
 */

session_start();

require_once 'conn.php';

if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
  $_SESSION['id'] =  $_GET['id'];
}

$result_pedido = "SELECT * FROM tb_produtos WHERE p_id = '{$_SESSION['id']}'"; 
$resultado_pedido = mysqli_query($conn, $result_pedido);
$pedidos = mysqli_fetch_all($resultado_pedido, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// If the user visits a path where the $_GET['id'] have result in
// database and the user specified that he / she want to save something
// to his / her cart.
if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id']) && !empty($pedidos)) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) $_SESSION['cart'] = []; // initialize if not exists.
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array_merge($_SESSION['cart'], $pedidos);
}
  
?>
```

**Note:** the quantity should be set to the cart somehow. You need to change the data structure to set or increment the "qty". But this is at least a start.